# find object of particular id in json in html tamplate

Tags: html, json, angular

I'm writing the page where I render posts.

in my controller I have:

```ts
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts$: Object;
  users$: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getPosts().subscribe(
      data => this.posts$ = data
    )
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => this.users$ = data
    )
  }

}
```

and in the template I iterate through the posts to render them:

```html
<h1>Posts</h1>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let post of posts$'>
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <h5>created by:</h5>
    <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

after 'created by: ' I would like to add `{{user$.username}}` where `user$` should be a user of post.userId from `users$` (already initialized in the controller). Methods `getUsers` and `getPosts` work fine and fetch the data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. I've got also `getUser(id)` method written and I thought I could use that one. It should be then in the controller:

```ts
this.data.getUser(id).subscribe(
  data => this.users$ = data
)
```

but I don't know where to get the `id` from as I iterate through posts in the template. Could you help me with that?

Comment: `<li *ngFor='let post of posts$; let i = index'>` you mean that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function `getUser(id)` in your component and let it return the user.

In your html

`{{ getUser(post.userId) }}`.

Or

```
this.data.getPosts().subscribe(
  data => { 
   for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     data[i].username = this.getUser(data[i].userId);
   }
   this.posts$ = data;
})
```

Comment: I get the concept, thanks! However for some reason in my component I cannot use this.posts$.length or this.posts$.forEach. It says that length and forEach are not defined for Object - which I understand. But I don't understand why I can use *ngFor='let post of posts$' in html then. And how to deal with it in the component.

Comment: I changed the code length should be available on `data` and after you can set it to `this.post$ = data`.